Vintage Motobecane ID
I found this vintage Motobecane bicycle on Facebook for $60 so I picked it up as a project bike. Can anyone help me identify the year and model? I am fairly new to the cycling world.
It has Abaresque Shimano 600 groupset. The seat post is fluted and says Laprade SR. The handlebars say CTA La Bonneville/Iton 27190 La Technique Avion Appliquee Aux 2 Roues France (Normandy). The pedals say Brevete SGDG AFA Made in France. The wheels say AVA made in France. The frame is a Reynolds 531.











Wow, this is a beautiful bike! Enjoy!

Gorgeous bike!  I'd guess it as being an `80s bike based on the overall look.
The chain clearly needs outright replacement due to rust, and its hanging weird or maybe mis-routed.
The front tyre in image #2 looks strange - we can see a tan sidewall on the right of the image but not the left.
I'd almost guarantee the brake blocks will be hard and awful, replacement of all four is strongly advised before riding.

Now the groupset is interesting - French bikes and Japanese groupsets weren't really a thing at first.  Either its been re-equipped with the 600 series Shimano, or perhaps it was stock with that setup.  Potentially telling.
Shimano 600 was first released in 1975 as a "mid range alternative to the racer's Dura Ace".  The "600 EX arablesque" was 1978 and the 600 AX was 1980.  Then the "new 600 EX" in 1983.  Finally the range ended in 1987 and was replaced with "Ultegra" 
Source, https://www.shimano.com/en/100th/history/products/17.php 
Another useful source of photos is  https://velobase.com/ViewGroup.aspx?GroupID=1320d0ea-538d-4762-9465-99089256c1d0  so try searching through there to match the components with yours.    Consider that you may not have a matched groupset with some parts being newer than others.
And the bike could be older or newer than the groupset, specially if it was a refit after the fact.

Thank you! I went ahead and broke the old chain and yes you are correct the brakes are rocks. Got the wheels off and the front one was full of black ants that were eating the old tube glue lol. I noticed the dropouts have a Huret logo. The fact that the frame has a glued on logo and no model decal makes me think it’s a Motobecane C 42 but I could be wrong. It’s hard to gather info on these.

@Bourbonguy42  tube glue?  So it probably has tubular tyres, not modern clinchers.  That alone might make you cautious - tubulars are notoriously difficult to deal with punctures specially on the road side.   I have one 80's bike which came with tubular rims/tyres, and I bought clincher wheels and tyres for it and have done 8000 km since then.

It's a pretty good match for a 1981 Grand Record.

Specifications page 1

Specifications page 2

Here is the link to the Motobecane catalog collection

Thanks what was throwing me was the glued on logo. Kinda think it’s a C42 but I’m not sure https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEgMCRWp7v9krvB-QesmN9_SYHplVmQUx1naX3N_uvQAxsU4OMePo_bVxmvhRVKX0kmbOv6VIfHkHNmiYB1RqUGRkKoDU8bYpd91T6NqVkBPfX-MTvAt6Iwo_hEIDH9FFuRmDWOSNxmvqRuX/s1600/Motobecane+1980+labibleduvelo+%252815%2529.jpg
